# bind() method position aurgument error problem

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, bind

In my project, I have added a bind method with button.

```
subbutton = Button(self, text='Submit', width=10)
subbutton.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky='w')
subbutton.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: controller.showframe(Moderator),
                       teacher_input(name.get(), idd.get(), username.get(), pas.get()),
                       MakeQuestion.qcurrent_user(username.get()), ExaminPaper.ecurrent_user(username.get()) )
```

These shows **bind have 1 to 4 positional augument you gave 5**. Why is this happening?

Comment: Why are you using lambda in this way? Your code would be considerably easier to debug if you created a proper function for the button. Is there a reason you're doing it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that all your function calls are part of the `lambda`, which they are not. Currently, only `controller.showframe(Moderator),` is. If you want to run multiple functions from your `lambda`, put them in a list like:

```
subbutton.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: [controller.showframe(Moderator),
                       teacher_input(name.get(), idd.get(), username.get(), pas.get()),
                       MakeQuestion.qcurrent_user(username.get()),
                       ExaminPaper.ecurrent_user(username.get())] )
```

---

However, putting many functions into one `lambda` call makes your code pretty difficult to understand and debug. You probably would be better off creating an extra function to bind to the button and call your extra functions from there. You also don't really need to use `bind` since the tkinter Button has a `command` option:

```
def buttonClick():
    controller.showframe(Moderator)
    teacher_input(name.get(), idd.get(), username.get(), pas.get())
    MakeQuestion.qcurrent_user(username.get())
    ExaminPaper.ecurrent_user(username.get())

subbutton = Button(self, text='Submit', width=10, command=buttonClick)
subbutton.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky='w')
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Here with lamda a event variable 'e' is given. If I add this with `MakeQuestion.qcurrent_user(e, username.get())` what is the difference? I didn't add an extra variable for this in the function arguments. It stops an warning. What this 'e' does?

Comment: `e` is the [event object](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) passed by the `bind` function. Your `lambda` has to accept it, but if your `MakeQuestion.qcurrent_user` function doesn't need it you shouldn't pass it.

Comment: Thanks. but it show user unfilled warning. code works same though.

Comment: It would be much better to not use lambda, and instead create a new function.

Comment: @BryanOakley Very true, and I guess I should have addressed that. I just focused on what was the cause of the error right now.

Comment: **curs.execute("SELECT Exam_Code FROM Written_Exam WHERE Teach_username = ?;", (user))**
**sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.**   What is going on here? @BryanOakley

Comment: @fhdrsdg Thanks for your help.